# Limiting what formats PIL image loads

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

To decrease the amount of possible attack vectors on a website, what would be the best way to limit formats Python Imaging Library can read to the set of known good codecs (GIF, JPEG, PNG).

This way the users could not submit more exotic formats and exploit possible codec bugs to do buffer overflow, etc. style attack.

Preferably in run-time.

Comment: What do you use to let users select a file to submit? A browse-to-file  popup or just an enter-url-here textbox? Why not intercept undesired files there instead of in PIL?

Comment: @Junuxx doing client side checks does not protect your service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) to check for accepted mimetypes before passing the file/buffer to PIL.